# How to access jar file from Unity with different bundle identifier in Unity & package name in Java?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have created a plugin for unity in java jar.

In Java, my package name is `com.android.test`.

In Unity, my Bundle Identifier is `com.android.test`. This is working fine with the code below.

But if I change my Bundle Identifier to `com.android.test2` in Unity, the code below throws an exception `Class not Found: com.android.test2.myplugin`.

Is there any way to access a jar file whose package name is different from Unity Bundle Identifier name?

Here is my unity C# code to access Jar:

```
static IntPtr cls_Activity;
static IntPtr fid_Activity;
static IntPtr obj_Activity;
static IntPtr cls_OurAppNameActivityClass;
static IntPtr startAdsMethod;

cls_Activity = AndroidJNI.FindClass("com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer");
fid_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticFieldID(cls_Activity, "currentActivity", "Landroid/app/Activity;");
obj_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticObjectField(cls_Activity, fid_Activity);

cls_OurAppNameActivityClass = AndroidJNI.FindClass("com/android/test/myplugin");
            startAdsMethod = AndroidJNI.GetMethodID(cls_OurAppNameActivityClass, "Instantiate", "()V");


  if (AndroidJNI.IsInstanceOf(obj_Activity, cls_OurAppNameActivityClass) != false)
    {
       Debug.Log("Activity IS a OurAppNameActivity");               
       jvalue[] myArray = new jvalue[1];
       AndroidJNI.CallVoidMethod(obj_Activity, startAdsMethod, myArray);
       Debug.Log("Activity Leaving a OurAppNameActivity");
    }
```

Comment: yeah i am also facing same problem.......waiting for answer..

Answer (score 0):

your package name needs to be same in both unity and in java else they cannot be accessed.

Comment: NO Shoaib.. There is a way.. using CallStatic().. but i m having some other issues with it.

Comment: thnks for leeting me  know  :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Follow the below steps

1.While creating android project give a name to your MainActivity
(instead of MainActivity Let us say MYAndroidPlugin)

2.Now in MYAndroidPlugin.java you will see the class MYAndroidPlugin,Modify it as follows`

```
package com.mydomain.androidplugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;



public class MyAndroidPlugin   {

   public MyAndroidPlugin(){

   //default constructor
  }

   public void makeToast(final String message, final int length) {
       final Activity a = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
       a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(a, message, length).show();
        }
    });
}
```

3.Export it as jar via gradle task and place jar file in you unityproject/Assets/Plugins/Android

4.in the c# script(in the toast method) directly refer your class

```
public void TestToast(){

 using(AndroidJavaObject jo =  new      AndroidJavaObject("com.mydomain.androidplugin.MYAndroidPlugin"))
        jo.Call ("makeToast", "my plugin worked", 2);
 }
```

5.That's it call this method to make a toast

you can now directly refer a jar of any identifier